# sbcl: encoding and decoding characters without actual I/O

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, common-lisp, sbcl

In sbcl, when encoding a string using, say, :utf-8, is there a way to encode it to a byte vector without doing actual I/O, similar to clisp's

```
(EXT:CONVERT-STRING-TO-BYTES string encoding &KEY :START :END)
```

and also decode with something like clisp's

```
(EXT:CONVERT-STRING-FROM-BYTES vector encoding &KEY :START :END)
```

I could crudely approximate this by writing the data to a file with the desired encoding and then rereading it using :iso-8859-1, but that seems to be a dorky longcut.

Comment: `SB-EXT:STRING-TO-OCTETS` and `SB-EXT:OCTETS-TO-STRING`.

Comment: @jkiiski Perfect! If you choose to make this an official answer, I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBCL has the functions `SB-EXT:STRING-TO-OCTETS` and `SB-EXT:OCTETS-TO-STRING` for this.

```
CL-USER> (sb-ext:string-to-octets "fööbär" :external-format :utf-8)
#(102 195 182 195 182 98 195 164 114)
CL-USER> (sb-ext:string-to-octets "fööbär" :external-format :iso-8859-1)
#(102 246 246 98 228 114)
CL-USER> (sb-ext:octets-to-string ** :external-format :utf-8)
"fööbär"
CL-USER> (sb-ext:octets-to-string ** :external-format :iso-8859-1)
"fööbär"
```

Answer (score 2):

For portable code, use [`babel`](https://github.com/cl-babel/babel), available from Quicklisp, which has `string-to-octets` and `octets-to-strings` like SBCL.