# sbcl: additional documentation for (for example) #'sb-ext:string-to-octets

Tags: documentation, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46260357/sbcl-encoding-and-decoding-characters-without-actual-i-o) about sbcl for which a response mentioned two functions of which I wasn't aware: `#'sb-ext:string-to-octets` and `#'sb-ext:octets-to-string`. In addition to answering my question, this also taught me that I should browse through the external symbols of package sb-ext to see what else might be of use.

My question (sbcl-related) is this: other than browsing through the external symbols of package sb-ext, is there some other manual which describes package sb-ext, and other additions (I'm trying to avoid the word "extension" because it's a specific technical term) to sbcl? `#'sb-ext:string-to-octets` and `#'sb-ext:octets-to-string`, for example, are not discussed in the [sbcl manual](http://sbcl.org/manual).

Comment: For things that aren't in the manual and don't have docstrings, reading the source (or at least comments near the thing of interest) is usually the best choice. SBCLs code is reasonably clear and well commented. For `STRING-TO-OCTETS` in particular there doesn't seem to be much documentation, probably because the function is rather self-explanatory.

Comment: one thing that I use is the repl-utilities for this. You can use the sb-ext-package and just do a (summary) to see all the doc-strings and then follow up with a M-. on the routines  of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in one answer in the other question by @svante, for things like that I prefer to use another libray for postabiliyt and usually well documented like [babel](http://quickdocs.org/babel/).

Normally for checking doc in common lisp if the symbol is in the ansi common lisp, you should check teh [clhs](http://clhs.lisp.se/) [sly](http://joaotavora.github.io/sly/#Documentation) and [slime](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Documentation.html) has an excelent facility for that.

And normally I proceed as follow:

```
CL-USER> (documentation 'sb-ext:octets-to-string 'function)
NIL
CL-USER> (describe 'sb-ext:octets-to-string)
SB-EXT:OCTETS-TO-STRING
  [symbol]

OCTETS-TO-STRING names a compiled function:
  Lambda-list: (VECTOR &KEY (EXTERNAL-FORMAT DEFAULT) (START 0) END)
  Derived type: (FUNCTION
                 ((VECTOR (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8)) &KEY (:EXTERNAL-FORMAT T)
                  (:START T) (:END T))
                 *)
  Source file: SYS:SRC;CODE;OCTETS.LISP
; No values
```

The describe function always get you relevant info about the symbol, then you can go to teh source using sly or slime is with `M-.`

```
(defun octets-to-string (vector &key (external-format :default) (start 0) end)
  (declare (type (vector (unsigned-byte 8)) vector))
  (with-array-data ((vector vector)
                    (start start)
                    (end end)
                    :check-fill-pointer t)
    (declare (type (simple-array (unsigned-byte 8) (*)) vector))
    (let ((ef (maybe-defaulted-external-format external-format)))
      (funcall (ef-octets-to-string-fun ef) vector start end))))
```

and finally you can go to teh repository for reading tests in this case going to the github SBCL repo and looking for this fucntion gives source code tests that you can read for getting an easy usage of the function:

https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=string-to-octets&type=

like this:

https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/622c9daf9bb41ef9ad4b8a063c62c4baf59a1c1a/tests/octets.pure.lisp